# What C is PS using to Determine Process Info Programmatically

Tags: c, ps

In both linux and macos we can get PID info, start time by using bash: `ps -p PID_HERE -o lstart=`.

I was going to use `lstat` and plan on it. But just out of curiosity:

Programatically `ps` has to be using `C` right? And in my use using the C functions is much faster, as I don't have to use `popen` to open and read.

In MacOSX/Darwin apparently they use something called `proc_pidinfo` and a topic on SO tells us how to do it here: [Determine Process Info Programmatically in Darwin/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx)

But what about in Linux? I couldn't find a such thing as `proc_pidinfo` for us.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589821/175814) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147622/175814) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939855/175814) on stackoverflow, `ps` uses the [proc file system](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) through [libproc](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) to gather process information. It appears that this is the preferred way to do it, so I would think `lstat(2)` is the right way™ to find out the start time of a process.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! Just wanted to make sure :)